# Typescript 2.6 -> Extend type definition for external library with module augmentation -> TS2339: Property '' does not exist on type ''

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, material-ui, typescript2.0

I'm using the library `material-ui` and I'm currently running the `v1.0.0-beta`. They updated the library yesterday to `v1.0.0-beta.28` but did not update the type definitions so my code fails at run time but not at compile time.

From Chrome:

> webpack-internal:///./node_modules/material-ui/styles/colorManipulator.js:80
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
>       at decomposeColor (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/material-ui/styles/colorManipulator.js:80)
>       at lighten (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/material-ui/styles/colorManipulator.js:226)
>       at createPalette (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/material-ui/styles/createPalette.js:144)
>       at Object.createMuiTheme (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/material-ui/styles/createMuiTheme.js:71)
>       at StartPage.render (webpack-internal:///./Features/Client/StartPage/index.tsx:106)
>       at finishClassComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:7873)
>       at updateClassComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:7850)
>       at beginWork (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:8225)
>       at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10224)
>       at workLoop (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10288)

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.28

Looking at the release notes I can see that the `palette` object has changed `primary` and `secondary` colors and it is a breaking change.

I then read about `module augmentation` and tried to extend the `Color` object in this case that needs new properties.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10859#issuecomment-246496707

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

I extended it like this:

```
import { Color } from 'material-ui'

declare module 'material-ui' {
  export interface Color {
    light?: string
    main?: string
    dark?: string
  }
}
```

[image]

Visual Studio picks it up and builds but when I try to run `webpack` I get the following error:

> TS2339: Property 'main' does not exist on type 'Color'.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error came from using a shared project and because of this type definitions were not loaded correctly, even if the `module augmentation` was present in the shared project as well. Will have to check our structure because it will probably lead to more errors in the future.