# webpack-dev-server and webpack -> output file to parent directory and have webpack-dev-server hot reloading still working

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

We have the following structure in our web application:

```
/src(.sln)
--/ClientSite
--/AdminSite
--/SharedWeb
```

In `SharedWeb` we have the following folders:

```
--/Client
--/Admin
--/Shared
```

We have this structure in order to have hot reloading with `webpack-dev-server` no matter what file we edit and only have one `package.json` etc. Thread about why we choose this structure if anyone is interested:

[Shared react front end components -> Separate project with TypeScript -> Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264414/shared-react-front-end-components-separate-project-with-typescript-visual/48265628#48265628)

Everything has worked fine so far but now that we need to deploy our solution we need to export the `bundle.js` to the correct site.

In `webpack.client.config.js`:

Works fine with hot reloading but script file is not exported to the site correctly:

```
output: {
    filename: "./Scripts/dist/[name].bundle.js",
},
```

Script file is exported correctly but hot reloading stops working:

```
output: {
    filename: "../ClientSite/Scripts/dist/[name].bundle.js",
},
```

Correct way with using path and filename according to documentation, nothing works:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts/dist/"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
}
```

Script file is exported correctly but hot reloading does not work. If I use `webpack` with `--watch` and manually reload `webpack-dev-server` URL I can see the changes but it does not reload automatically.

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../ClientSite/Scripts/dist/"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it like this, `publicPath` was the key for automatic updates to work in `webpack-dev-server`.

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../ClientSite/Scripts/dist/"),
    publicPath: '/Scripts/dist',
    filename: "[name].bundle.js"
},
```

https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath